# Handle multiple modelforms in one html form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

A user will have photos which will be related with their specific album.

So this was the model for that:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_privacy = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=PRIVACY, default='F')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    caption = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

Views.py:

```
def create_album(request, user_name):
    user = User.objects.get(username=unquote(user_name))
    if request.method=='POST':
        pform = AlbumPhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        aform = AlbumForm(request.POST)
        p_valid = pform.is_valid()
        a_valid = aform.is_valid()
        if p_valid and a_valid:
            photo = pform.save(commit=False)
            album = aform.save(commit=False)
            photo.user = user
            album.user = user
            album.save()
            photo.album = album
            photo.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/'+user.username+'/photos')
        else:
            return render(request, 'create_album.html',{
                'pform':pform,
                'aform':aform
            })
    else:
        pform = AlbumPhotoForm()
        aform = AlbumForm()
        return render(request, 'create_album.html', {
            'pform':pform,
            'aform':aform
        })
```

And the form:

```
<form action="/{{ user.username }}/create_album/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ aform.as_p }}

    {{ pform.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create and Upload Album"/>
</form>
```

This works fine if I only have to upload one file (photo) with that form.

**Update:**

However what I want to do is, show minimum of three input for uploading photos to the new album:

```
<form action="/{{ user.username }}/create_album/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ aform.as_p }}

    {{ pform.as_p }}
    {{ pform.as_p }}
    {{ pform.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create and Upload Album"/>
</form>
```

When doing so, only the last `pform` is gets saved. And the other two `pform`'s are ignored. How do I get to save all the three forms of photo (`pform`) accordingly?

Or is there any other way around? Your help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/). They do exactly what you want:

```
from django.forms.models import formset_factory

PhotoFormSet = formset_factory(AlbumPhotoForm, can_delete=False,
                               min_num=1, validate_min=True,
                               max_num=3, validate_max=True,
                               extra=3)

def create_album(request, user_name):
    user = User.objects.get(username=unquote(user_name))
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AlbumForm(request.POST)
        formset = PhotoFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if all([form.is_valid(), formset.is_valid()]):
            album = form.save(commit=False)
            album.user = user
            album.save()
            for photo_form in formset:
                if photo_form.cleaned_data:
                    photo = photo_form.save(commit=False)
                    photo.album = album
                    photo.user = user
                    photo.save()
            return redirect('/%s/photos' % user.username )
    else:
        form = AlbumForm()
        formset = PhotoFormSet()
    return render(request, 'create_album.html',
                  {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

And template may look like this:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}    
    <table>
        {{ formset }}
    </table>    
    <input type="submit" value="Create and Upload Album"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I think you didn't get me. Or may be I am not getting you. I have updated the question. Would you please have a look at it. Thank you.